# Lebesgue Integral of Lebesgue Measure Function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm curious about how to prove the following claim:

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ both with finite Lebesgue measure. Let $f(x)=m(A\cap (B+x))$, then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)=m(A)m(B)$$ where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Consider a double integral?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I've considered it. But I'm still not sure how to piece it together...

Comment: $m(A)m(B)=\int_A\int_B1\,dx\,dy$. I'd now try a change of variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That follows from Fubini's theorem:

$$\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R} f &=\int_\mathbb{R}\Big(\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_A(y)\mathbb{1}_{B+x}(y)\,dy\Big)\,dx=\int_\mathbb{R}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{A}(y)\mathbb{1}_B(y-x)_\,dy\Big)\,dx\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_A(y)\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_B(y-x)_\,dx\Big)\,dy=\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_A(y)\,m(y-B)\,dy=m(A)m(B)
\end{align}$$
where the last equality follows from translation invariance and symmetry of the Lebesgue measure, i.e. $\mu(V+h)=m(V)$ for all $h$, and $m(-U)=m(U)$ for all measurable set $U$.